When is a subspace of a complex vector space a complexification?
(When is a subspace of a complex vector space a complexification?) Let $V$ be a real vector space with complexification and let $U$ be a subspace of $V^\mathbb C $. Prove that there is a subspace of $V$ for which
$$ U=S^\mathbb C = \{s+i.t : s,t \in S \}$$
if and only if is closed under complex conjugation$\mathcal X : V^\mathbb C \to V^\mathbb C$ defined by $  \mathcal X(u+iv)=u-iv$
$\Rightarrow : $ Let $u+iv \in U (u,v \in S ) $Since $S \subset V $ is a subspace then $u,-v \in S \Rightarrow u-iv \in U$
I tried  to prove " $\Leftarrow $" but I couldn't. Then I find a proof in an internet site but I think it's wrong, In that proof they is taking $S$ like this:
$$ S = \{v \in V : v= \frac{1}{2} (u+ \mathcal X(u)) ,u \in U \}$$
then proving that $S$ is a subspace and $ U=S^\mathbb C = \{s+i.t : s,t \in S \}$.
My problem with this proof that I see that $S \subset V ^\mathbb C $ that because
For $u \in U \Rightarrow u =a+ib , a,b \in V $ So
$v= \frac{1}{2} (a+ib+ \mathcal X(a+ib))=v= \frac{1}{2} (a+ib+a-ib)= a +i.0 $
I know that we usually write $a+i.o=a $ and that looks like it is an element in $V$. But it is not true. In fact  here $a \in V \times \{0\}.$

$V$ is isomorphic (as a real vector space) to the subspace ${x + i\cdot 0 \mid x \in V} \subset V^{\mathbb{C}}$, which you denote $V \times {0}$. When we talk about complexifications, we usually assume that $V \subset V^{\mathbb{C}}$ by identifying $V$ with $V \times {0}$.

@VladimirLysikov the set $S$ above is a subset of $V$. Isn't there a problem with it? Right?

Yes, we have $S \subset V \subset V^{\mathbb{C}}$. I don't see a problem.

Well. Thank you
